# selenium get sruck on "findElementBy"

Tags: java, selenium

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/me/selenium-2.53.1/chromedriver");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--incognito"));
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

            driver.get("http://www/.google.com");
            WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("#myButton"));

            el.click();
            driver.close();

       }
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

However my code never returns from `driver.findElement(By.id("#myButton"));`

not even returning a null element

How can i fix this?

Comment: Try as :- `driver.findElement(By.id("myButton"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#myButton` will work with `By.cssSelector()`.. if you want to locate element using `By.id()`,  no need to append `#` try as below:-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("myButton"));
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: then why haven't it returned a null object?

Comment: @EladBenda `findElement` never returns null.. it will give either element or throw exception....if you want to test like this you can use `findElements` instead.. it will return either list of elements or empty list....:)

Answer (score 0):

You would use `#myButton` with a `By.cssSelector()` locator:

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#myButton"));
```

In case of `By.id()` omit the `#`:

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("myButton"));
```